# node: wait for async multiple images load to finish

Tags: node.js, http, async-await

I am aware that similar questions have been asked before. Still I am not able to solve the problem i have. I need to load a bunch of images before executing another part of code.

```
(async () => {
  const urls = <array of urls>
  await urls.map(url => {
    const filename = path.basename(url);
    const localPath = imagesPath + '/' + filename;
    return loadImageToPath(url, localPath);
  });
  console.log('done');
})();

async function loadImageToPath(url, localPath) {
  const file = fs.createWriteStream(localPath);
  return await http.get(url, function (response) {
    console.log('Image loaded: ' + localPath);
    response.pipe(file);
  });
}
```

Can someone please share some light on this!

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Map is returning an array of promises, to wait all promises to resolve use  `Promise.all()`, [MDN reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
(async () => {
   const urls = <array of urls>
   const promises = await urls.map(url => {
       const filename = path.basename(url);
       const localPath = imagesPath + '/' + filename;
       return loadImageToPath(url, localPath);
   });
   const responses = await Promise.all(promises)  // this line waits all promises to resolve
   console.log('done');
 })();
```

Comment: I tried this code and still i get the output 'done' and afterwards the output that the images are loaded and saved to the local path. 

It need all the images loaded and stored first.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the code and it is working now. I thought that http is returning a promise by itself. With a wrapper that returns a promise it is working now.

```
(async () => {
  const urls = <array of urls>
  await urls.map(url => {
    const filename = path.basename(url);
    const localPath = imagesPath + '/' + filename;
    return loadImageToPath(url, localPath);
  });
  console.log('done');
})();

async function loadImageToPath(url, localPath) {
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(localPath);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        http.get(url, function (response) {
            console.log('Image loaded: ' + localPath);
            response.pipe(file);
            resolve();
        });
  });
}
```